# Is 'boarding the plane' more formal than 'getting on the plane'?

Tags: politeness

When I go to an airport, the airport announcement announces 'boarding a plane' than 'getting on a plane'.

Because they say in public places all the time, I start to feel 'boarding' is a more formal word than 'getting on'.

Let's say I talk with a friend and the friend asks me what I'm doing.

If I say,

> I'm boarding a plane.

Does this make the mood a bit unfriendly?

Instead, do I have to say

> I'm getting on a plane.

Comment: It is both more formal and more normal. Similarly at a function, an announcement might be "we are now serving dinner" rather than the childish "we will now be bringing food to the tables." But over the phone you can say "I am just getting on the plane" or "we are boarding now".

Comment: Another difference between "boarding" and "getting on" is that you can say "flight 123 is boarding at gate 15". You wouldn't hear "flight 123 is getting on...".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty That is very true!

Comment: Yes, the accurate, technical term is boarding. However, in spoken English, get on a plane is 100% correct.

Answer (score 7):

The word "boarding" is not reserved for formal use - it's just the *correct* term for "getting on" most kinds of public transportation, but particularly planes and boats. It is commonly used in all contexts, formal and informal. A plane ticket is exchanged for a 'boarding pass' and in my experience of air travel all passenger announcements use the term, so it isn't surprising that it is in most people's vocabulary and in everyday use.

You can "get on" lots of things, so it's a very broad phrase. You might say you "got on a horse", but the correct term would be *mounted*.

Not only that, but in the case of transportation, "get on" is arguably a shortened way of saying "*get onboard*" anyway.

Comment: Announcements at airports which are formal use board. They would not say get on. Ergo, this is wrong.

Comment: @Lambie Have you misread? I haven't said that airport announcements *aren't* formal, nor have I said that an airport announcer would say anything other than "board". I said there is nothing particularly formal about the word "board". It is used both formally and informally. Ergo, I'm right.

Comment: You said; I wouldn't say that boarding is formal.

Comment: @Lambie "The plane is now boarding". Is the word "now" formal? Just because someone uses a word in a formal statement doesn't make that word formal. I mean that is isn't *reserved* for formal use, not that it would never be used in a formal setting.

Comment: Passengers are now boarding the plane.(formal and industry use) = Passengers are now getting on the plane (spoken and informal use).

Comment: @Lambie Have to agree to disagree. "Getting on" is certainly more *informal*, but I can't agree that the word "boarding" makes it "formal" (done in accordance with convention or etiquette; suitable for or constituting an official or important occasion). I would say boarding in casual speech, and I'm working class with no advanced education.

Answer (score 2):

I always view formality by asking myself how it would be written in a formal setting:  Please board the plane by row number vs Please get on the plane by row number. Obviously boarding is a formal use.
Similarly with have and have got.  Filling in your passport application= Do you have any children vs Sitting in pub chatting with a stranger= Have you got any children.

Comment: Yes, exactly my point in my other comments.